# Invalid .ost file and no Mail icon in Control Panel to fix it

Tags: email, windows-8, office365, office-2013, control-panel

I have a really interesting situation here. I'm running Windows 8 Pro x64 with Office 2013 (Office 365, more specifically) running. Somewhere while I was setting up Outlook, I made a mistake causing it to create in invalid .ost file. I found the file in Explorer and it happens to be an empty file.

All the solutions to this involve using the Mail icon in the Control Panel. That'd be great, but it **doesn't exist!** I've searched and searched for solutions to this issue, and I can't find a single one that applies to Windows 8. Either the solution is so outdated that it's not even usable in Windows 8, or the solution somehow doesn't work with my setup.

I've come to an absolute end of ideas for this, and I've decided to come to see if anyone here can wrestle down my problem. Thanks for your help!

Edit: I've thought of a few possible solutions, and the only one that seems remotely feasible seems to be to completely restart the Outlook setup process. However, I can't figure out how to do this, and I can't reinstall just Outlook because it's part of Office 365. Any help on this would be incredibly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting (or renaming/moving, to be more cautious) the empty .ost file?  Once it's not there, that may cause Outlook to regenerate it properly.

Is there anything listed in your "Add/remove programs" for Outlook 2013 or Office 365?  I've been running Outlook 2013 (in its beta glory) for awhile, and I occasionally have issues which are fixed by doing a quick repair.

To do a quick repair:

- Press Windows key + Q.  Search for "remove programs" and change the search scope filter to "Settings".
- Select "Change or remove a program".
- I have "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 - en-us" as one of my programs.  Click that (or something similar for Office 2013) and then click "Change".
- Select "Quick Repair" and click "Repair".

Finally, if none of that works, here's how to find the Mail icon in the Control Panel:

- Bring the mouse to the bottom right corner of the screen (where the Start button used to be) and right-click.  Select "Control Panel".
- In Control Panel in the upper right-hand corner, there is a "View by" dropdown menu.  It may be set to "Category".  Change it to "Large icons".
- I now see a Mail icon.  If it's not showing up for you, that probably means that Outlook wasn't configured properly and you do need to reinstall.

Hope this helps.